# Force save dialog in browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a functionality, where I am downloading a configuration. I have wrote a method, which works fine and does what I want. The only problem is that the user is not able to change a filename and specify destination.

I tried several options from SO, like Stream, FileResult, ActionResult, Response, but the save dialog does not appear at all.

Here is the function:

```
public void DownloadParameters()
    {
        var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.GetParameters()));
        var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
        string fileName = "tmp.file";

        System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        response.ClearContent();
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "text/html";
        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+fileName+";");
        response.BinaryWrite(byteArray);
        response.Flush();
        response.End();
    }
```

Is there any other way to achieve this? Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: How are you using this Method?, is it in an MVC Controller or WebApi?

Comment: It is in controller. Like I have another HTTP post method, where I check if the user has chosen the option to save parameters then I call this method.

Comment: If you want a dialogue to show you'll need to have like
 `<form><input type="file" name="file">
<br />
<button type="submit">Submit</button></form>` on your html

Comment: The problem is your content type. You're using text/html. You shouldn't be. The browser will always try to handle the document itself if using this content-type.

Comment: A working answer has been provided. Kindly consider marking it as such.

Answer (score 0):

It may be due to the content type.

Is there a reason you're using text/html?

If you change to a more appropriate content type, something not natively handled by a browser, the save dialog should be displayed.

Since the content is obviously json, a more appropriate name might be "config.json" and content type should be "application/json".

If you use that, the save dialog should appear.